# UV Inset / Shrink/Fatten

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I was wondering if there is a way to replicate the **inset** or **shrink/fatten** behaviour but for UVs.
Something similar to the attached image, I want to scale the uv island down but scaling it inwards if it makes sense.

[image: uv inset shrink fatten] Many thanks.

Comment: If no one has a better idea, I could write a script that copies UV map as a 2D geometry, and apply selected geometry as new UV coordinates in the UV map...

Comment: I don't think it is possible with Blender's native tools, so it definitely would be amazing to have a script for that. I'm also trying to learn some python (for blender) and would be very interested to see what you come up with, @MarkusvonBroady

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Python script [image]

Select geometry of interest (<kbd>A</kbd> to select all) and run this script:

```py
import bpy, bmesh, json
from bpy import context as C, data as D

save_name = "uv_inset_data"
if save_name in D.texts:
    raise ResourceWarning(f"text '{save_name}' already exists, perhaps you want to run the other script")
save = D.texts.new(save_name)

for s in (s for a in C.screen.areas for s in a.spaces if s.type=="VIEW_3D"):
    s.shading.type = "RENDERED"  # just for convenience

me = C.active_object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
old_verts = bm.verts[:]
selected_faces = [f for f in bm.faces if f.select]
uvm = bm.loops.layers.uv[0]

new_vertices = []
new_faces = []
facemap = {} 
for f in selected_faces:
    g = bmesh.ops.duplicate(bm, geom=[f] + f.edges[:] + f.verts[:])
    new_f = g["face_map"][f]
    new_f.loops.index_update()
    new_faces.append(new_f)
    new_vertices += new_f.verts[:]
    for i, l in enumerate(new_f.loops):
        l.vert.co.xyz = *l[uvm].uv, 0  # map u to x, v to y, set z to 0
        facemap[new_f.index] = f.index
    for x in [f] + f.edges[:] + f.verts[:]:
        x.select = False

bmesh.ops.remove_doubles(bm, verts=new_vertices, dist=0.0001)

for f in new_faces:
    f.select_set(True)
bm.select_flush_mode()
 
for v in old_verts:
    v.hide_set(True)

save.from_string(json.dumps(facemap))
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

It duplicates the geometry and puts it on Z=0 plane, also moving all vertices to coordinates of UV their UV mapping. This way the shape becomes exactly the same as it's 2D UV unwrapped version. Also a text `uv_inset_data` is saved with information on the original faces and which relates to which.

[image]

Now inset those newly created faces, keep them selected...

[image]

...and run the script below:

```py
import bpy, bmesh, json
from bpy import context as C, data as D

save_name = "uv_inset_data"
save = D.texts.get(save_name)
if not save:
    raise ResourceWarning(f"Couldn't load the {save_name} text, did the first script finish successfully?")
facemap = json.loads(save.as_string())

me = C.active_object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

selected_faces = [f for f in bm.faces if f.select]
uvm = bm.loops.layers.uv[0]
for f in selected_faces:
    for i, l in enumerate(f.loops):
        old_face_i = facemap[str(f.index)]  # json converts keys to strings
        orig_loop = bm.faces[old_face_i].loops[i]
        orig_loop[uvm].uv = l[uvm].uv  # inset operator updated UV, otherwise could use l.vert.xy

bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=[v for v in bm.verts if not v.hide])  # remove visible
for v in bm.verts:
    v.hide_set(False)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
D.texts.remove(save)
```

[image]

Comment: That is brilliant! Works like a charm :) @MarkusvonBroady
Thanks so much for taking the time to write the script. I think that it would be great to have that capability in Blender, and in general it seems that the UVs didn't get any love from the developers, thanks a lot!